# How to init a ES6 module for each on-page element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I'm trying to create a ES6 module that can be initialized multiple times (once for each instance of an on-page element).

I have a page with 3 video components on it, I want to toggle the class of 'playing' on the video that the click came from. However only the instance of the last video is ever having the class toggled.

Could someone please help..? I can't for the life of me get the code running for each individual instance.

index.html

```
<div class="video">...</div>
<div class="video">...</div>
<div class="video">...</div>
```

main.js

```
import * as video from './video';

var $videos = $('.video');

$.each($videos, function(i, $video) {

  video.build($video);

});
```

video.js

```
export function build (videoInstance) {

  $(videoInstance).on('click', function (e) {

    $(this).toggleClass('playing');

  });

}
```

Comment: Depending on the video control, it may have examples for this already. What is the video module you're using?

Comment: Hi, it’s not the video that’s the problem. I have simplified the example for readability. The issue is around ES6 modules. If I replaced all references to the word video in the example with “foo” then the same problem would still exist. Thanks.

Comment: ES6 Modules cannot be loaded and evaluated multiple times, but that doesn't appear to be what you're doing anyway. You have one function `build`, and calling it multiple times on different elements should definitely work. Please put a breakpoint in there and do some debugging.

Comment: @Bergi yes you're right... I am trying to call the method for each element on the page, but the actual instance always reverts to the last one on the page, I believe it is something to do with the basic way I'm importing the module, instead of assigning it to a var. But I still can't figure it out.

Comment: No, the import is fine. Is the `build` function your actual code?